# How to solve stack trace error

Tags: c++, cygwin, runtime-error

I am writing a program to get prime numbers by trial division. First it sieves all primes below `2^32`, then It test `2^64-1` and below for primality.
With the code mentioned below I get, while executing:

> Initializing... 
>   done. 
>   710 [main] a 15444 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to a.exe.stackdump.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

bool* SieveOfEratosthenes(unsigned long long number) {
    bool* prime = new bool[number + 1];
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i <= number; i++)
        prime[i] = true;
    // 0 and 1 are not prime, and we mark because we do not check in the
    // algorithm
    //(because will cause bad results, if we divide by 0, we go to hell, and if
    //we divide one by one, we will mark all numbers a nonprime.
    prime[0] = false;
    prime[1] = false;
    unsigned long squareRoot = sqrt(number);
    for (unsigned long i = 2; i <= squareRoot; i++) {
        // If is gray (Is prime)
        if (prime[i]) {
            // cout << i << ",";
            // We start j by the next multiple of i (that is: 2*i), and we
            // increase it by i each time until j is less than or equal to
            // sqrt(number)
            for (unsigned long j = i * i; j <= number; j += i)
                prime[j] = false;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}

int main() {
    printf("Initializing...");
    unsigned long number = 4294967295;
    unsigned long long c;
    bool* primes;
    unsigned long* p;
    p = new unsigned long[203280221];
    primes = SieveOfEratosthenes(number);
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        if (primes[i] == true) {
            // cout << i << endl;
            p[c] = i;
            // cout << p[c] << endl;
            c++;
        }
    }
    delete[] primes;
    printf("done.\n");
    for (c = 18446744073709551615; c > 1; c -= 2) {
        unsigned long root = (unsigned long)sqrt(c);
        unsigned long i = 0;
        bool flag = true;
        while (p[i] <= root) {
            cout << "DEBUG: Test " << p[i];
            if (c % p[i] == 0) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == true)
            cout << c << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info, then use a debugger.

Comment: Certainly one problem might be that you do `number = 4294967295`, then pass that to `SieveOfEratosthenes`, which promptly calls `new` with that value -- do you really have 4GB contiguous memory space available when you run this program? Is it compiled for a 64-bit architecture?

Comment: @Cameron: With many systems, it takes 16GB, so will always fail in 32bit arch.

Comment: @Mooing: Good to know. Wouldn't it always fail under 32-bit architectures even if it was only 4GB? (There still has to be room for the stack too in the address space...)

Comment: @Cameron: Fair point

Answer (score 4):

The exception most probably is `out of memory`.

You are allocating `4294967295 bool` in `SieveOfEratosthenes` function. Depending the platform and compiler bool could be **1 byte** or **4 byte**. With bool size `1 byte` the result is 4096Mb allocation (`4Gb`), if the program is compiled in 32bits an error is certain.

In main you are allocating other 775Mb for `p` (assuming `unsigned long` size 4 byte)

If you are compiling with GCC try add the parameter `-m64` to compile in 64bits mode, if you are using Visual Studio in the properties of the project change the target to `x64`.

You could change the `bool` array to `std::vector<bool>` in most of the implementation of the `STL` are implemented as `bit` (in one `unsigned long` is saved 32 bool values), this mean that `4294967295 bool` would be `511Mb`